# How to make Vuetify v-flex occupy rest of the available space

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have two flex inside a v-layout(fill-height).
Problem: The second flex is aligned to end which is expected, but the first flex does not occupy the rest of the available space.

```
  <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap fill-height>
        <v-flex
          xs12
          class="white--text green darken-3"
        >
            <v-card-text>I should occupy rest of the available space</v-card-text>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex
          xs12
          align-self-end
          class="white--text blue darken-3"
        >   

        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/MWaapYR?editors=1000

I am new to vuetify and above codepen is what I have tried till now ,is there any way to make flex1 occupy rest of the available space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **Vuetify 1.5**:

Use `column` and then remove the `xs12` prop. Then shrink/grow will work as expected (**no extra CSS or inline styles**):

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout column fill-height>
        <v-flex
          grow
          class="white--text green darken-3"
        >
            <v-card-text>
              I should occupy rest of the available space
            </v-card-text>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex
          shrink
          align-self-end
          class="white--text blue darken-3"
        >   
            <v-card-text>
              I should stay here
            </v-card-text>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

1.5 Demo: https://codeply.com/p/JjD6UZdtjU

---

With **Vuetify 2.x**:

Works the same except `v-row, v-col` are used instead of `v-layout, v-flex`:

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-container class="fill-height">
            <v-row class="no-gutters flex-wrap flex-column fill-height">
                <v-col cols="auto" class="grow pink pa-2">
                    <h1>Content</h1>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="auto" class="shrink blue pa-2"> Footer </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

2.x Demo: https://codeply.com/p/07CA4jZNAl

Comment: The Vuetify 2.x example!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
<v-layout column wrap fill-height>
  <v-flex
    style="flex:1"
    xs12
    class="white--text green darken-3"
  >
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex
    style="flex:0; width: 100%"
    xs12
    align-self-end
  >
    <v-card
      dark
      color="blue darken-1"
     >
      <v-card-text>I should stay here</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```